# How would I answer the following questions on determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

"Assume that A and B are 9 x 9 matrices with det A = 7 and det B = -3. Then:

det(-2A) = ?

det(A^4) = ?

det(B^-5) = ?

det(ABA^-1) = ?

det((A^T)A) = ?

det((A^-1)^T(B^T)^-1) = ?"

I know the general ideas about row and column exchanges and how those affect the determinant. But I am a little unsure on how to deal with powers, scalar multiples, inverses and transposes. Are there any rules related to these as well?

Any assistance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Could you solve the exercise?

Comment: @A.Smith Yes I managed to in the end. Thanks to the answer below. :)

Answer (score 2):

The determinant satisfies the following properties:

1. $\det(A^{\top})=\det(A)$
2. $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ for square matrix of equal size.
3. $\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(A)}$ if $A$ is invertible
4. $\det(\lambda A)=\lambda^n \det(A)$ if $\lambda$ is a scalar. Here $n$ is dimensionality of the square matrix $A$.

With these properties you will be able to find the answers you want because you know that $\det(A)=7$ and $\det(B)=-3$.

I hope that helps.